# Bounding the limit of a sequence with some terms of another sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I have the following problem involving real sequences. It is not taken from any book nor it is some assignment. I just have a bigger problem that has been reduced. So it is even possible that what I am supposed to prove is indeed false.

Fix two real positive constants $L$ and $C$ with $L>C$. We can take $L$ arbitrarily bigger than $C$.

Moreover consider two real sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ having the following properties:

- $a_n>0$ and $b_n>0$ for any $n$
- $b_n\to +\infty$ and $b_n$ is increasing
- $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n+L}<+\infty$

Put now by simplicity $f_n:=\frac{a_n}{b_n+L}$ and $g_n:=\frac{a_n}{b_n+C}$.

> Is it possible to find $M$ (any $M>1$) terms $g_{n_1},\ldots, g_{n_M}$ in the
> sequence $g_n$ such that
>
> $$ \lim_{n\to+\infty} f_n < g_{n_k}\quad  \text{ for } k=1,\ldots, M \quad\text{?}$$

The main problem is that $g_n-f_n\to 0$. In fact this is my attempt: take $\epsilon>0$ then for $n>N$ we have

$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty} f_n< f_n+\epsilon
$$

Now choose our $g_{n_k}$ such that $n_k>N$ and define $\delta_k:=g_{n_k}-f_{n_k}>0$, then **if**   $\epsilon < \min\{\delta_1,\ldots, \delta_k\}$ we have

$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty} f_n< f_{n_k}+\epsilon < f_{n_k}+\delta_k= g_{n_k}
$$

Here I am stuck and I am not able to conclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not always possible. Take for example $a_n = b_n$. Since $b_n$ goes to infinity, the limit of $f_n$ is $1$. On the other hand,
$$\forall \, {n\in {\bf N}}, \ g_n = {a_n \over a_n + C} < 1.$$
The desired inequality is never satisfied.

Comment: Ok, clear. But also if I assume $a_n\neq b_n$ I can find a counterexample? I forgot to add it to the hypotheses

Comment: Let $a_n=cb_n$. You can do weirder things too, like $a_n=cb_n+d/n$, just to make them linearly independent.